# Change swatches images size

Tags: magento2, swatches, dimensions

I can't change the image size of the swatches of my product.

In My/Theme/etc, I have a view.xml file.

I've added this :

```
    <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
        <width>50</width>
        <height>50</height>
    </image>
    <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
        <width>150</width>
        <height>130</height>
    </image>
    <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
        <width>50</width>
        <height>50</height>
    </image>
    <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
        <width>150</width>
        <height>130</height>
    </image>
```

Inside

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
```

I've refreshed my cache, used catalog:images:resize but there no changes.

I've seen that's a known issue, but can find the way to fix it. I'm on magento 2.2.4